# How to have regex stop after I acquire a value?

Tags: python, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am parsing data from a database. I created a connection to the database, then ran the query, iterating over each row for specific attributes in the data. When I run my code I am getting none of the values that I am searching for.

I am specifically looking to get all the Confidence values that are associated with one value in each row.

This is what I have so far.

1. JSON block I am trying to parse (this is just a portion of the JSON block):

```
{"HealthPiQturePotentialConditions":{"PotentialCondition":[{"Condition":"Beign a great guy","HeaderCode":"111","ContributingFactors":"Free X, Orange, GreatGuy factor, aPTT","Confidence":"99.0%","ProviderGenerated":true,"DemographicPrevalence":"0.2%"},{"Condition":"Some Disease","HeaderCode":"E11","ContributingFactors":"High Ego","Confidence":"99.0%","ProviderGenerated":true,"DemographicPrevalence":"64.6%"},{"Condition":"Polywag","HeaderCode":"R11","ContributingFactors":"Master mind","Confidence":"99.0%","ProviderGenerated":false,"DemographicPrevalence":"Yellow"},{"Condition":"Muscles","HeaderCode":"M11","ContributingFactors":"Master of None","Confidence":"99.0%","ProviderGenerated":true,"DemographicPrevalence":"61.3%"}
```

2. My SQL Connection and Query:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'X',
    port = 'X',
    user = 'X',
    passwd = 'X',
    database = 'product'
)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
SELECT a.ID, a.lab_data from `product`.LAB_data a
inner join `Analytical`.Decline_lab b
on a.id = b.ID;;
""")
```

My function:

```
def reason_decline(row):
    Bs_data = BS(row)

    ID = Bs_data.find_all("p")

       

    if re.findall("{Condition:(.*?)}", ID[0].string.replace('"', '')) != []:
            nodes4 = re.findall(',"Confidence":\s*"([^"]+),', ARCID[0].string.replace('"', ''))
            Confidence = nodes4
            Conf_lvls = []
            for c in Confidence:
                Conf_lvls.append(c)


    else:
        return 0

    


    return Conf_lvls
```

My output:

```
Confidence_lvl_lst = []

for row in cursor:
    Conf_lvls1 = reason_decline(row[1])
    if Conf_lvls1 != 0:
        Confidence_lvl_lst.append(Conf_lvls1)

 Confidence_lvl_lst
[[],
 [],
...
 [],
 [],
 []]
```

Other regex expressions I have tried:

```
"Confidence":\s*"([^"]+),"

"Confidence":"([^"]+)"
```

I am expecting to get:

```
[[99.0%, 99.0%, 99.0%, 99.0%, 99.0%], .....]
```

The leading dots are for iterating over the other rows in my database.

Comment: That's JSON, not XML. Regex is the wrong tool. You should decode it into a native object and iterate it or use a library like JSONPath if you wish for expression-like execution.

Comment: You are right on the JSON file, so I have been able to parse other attributes like Condition using this regex expression nodes3 = re.findall("{Condition:(.*?),", ARCID[0].string.replace('"', '')). I figured I could use the same to get Confidence.

Comment: You're trying to filet a fish with a hammer, stop it. Just parse and iterate JSON like a normal programmer.

Comment: That is the thing, in my database, it doesn't come as a JSON file it is str. Hence why I have the code setup the way I do.

Comment: Right, JSON is a standardized string which is supposed to be decoded by whatever language wishes to access the data. Look up the "Decoding JSON" section from the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
nodes4 = re.findall('Confidence:(.*?),', ARCID[0].string.replace('"', ''))
            Confidence = nodes4
            Conf_lvls = []
            for c in Confidence:
                Conf_lvls.append(c)
```

It was just adding the , symbol at the end, and using (.*?) for the regex expression to get any and all values after the word Confidence attribute occurs.